# android tabbar on every activity

Tags: android, tabbar, android-tabhost

i have a tabbar in my android application , in each tab there is a flow of 5 to 7 activities further,
all these activities must show the tab bar, so i intent in each activity using activitygroup and getLocalActivityManager like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, activity2.class);

                     mView = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("id", intent
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    )
                    .getDecorView();

                    setContentView(mView);
```

and i set the backbutton of this activity1 as

```
        mView.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

so the control of back button goes to that intented activity2

then in that intented activity2 back button i override to intent to the last activity , as
        @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //Back key pressed
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activity1.class);
        mView = NearByActivity.mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("activity1", intent
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                )
                .getDecorView();

                setContentView(mView);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

it works fine for 2 activities but not for 5 to 6 activities in the tab
when i click on back button on 3rd activity it does not override back button , it uses the activity2 back button and goes to activity 1 instead of 2

how this can be solved doing 6 7 intents in one tab content

Comment: Activity Group is deprecated. you have to go for fragments.

Comment: can u give me an example on how to use fragments for this issue

Comment: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/  http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html

Answer (score -1):

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() { 
    try{
        Listentab.group.back();
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        finish();
    }

Use this in your activity where you extends activitygroup

Comment: For every tab u have to create one main activity which extends activity group....here listentab means one of the tab class in that write the code